# Is 'learn' the new 'teach'?

Tags: meaning, slang

With seemingly increasing frequency I come across a phrase using 'learn' when I think it should be 'teach'.

The classic example is 'that will learn them!', as in "Shoot all criminals - that will learn them!". I thought this was being deliberately wrong for comedic effect, in keeping with the general sentiment of the sentence.

Another example from a Stack Exchange site (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/53880/stuff-you-should-have-learned-in-school-but-didnt-pay-attention-to-at-the-time)

> I don't know if you can learn someone
>   to write at this age

Am I being overly fussy/old fashioned or is this just wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In standard English, using *learn* to mean *teach* is incorrect. It is, however, a feature of some non-standard dialects. The examples you give all seem to be to be using *learn* for comedic effect, mimicking the non-standard dialects where this sort of thing is common.

Comment: In the same (rural US) dialects where you hear "learn" instead of "teach" you also often hear "bring" and "take" interchanged, and occasionally "come" and "go".

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there are two different Old English words in question: *leornian*, meaning "to acquire knowledge", and *læran*, meaning "to teach". Both developed into the Modern English form "learn" (and the latter into the participial form "learned",  i.e. "well-taught". German has cognates *lernen* and *lehren* with the same respective meanings.

According to Etymonline.com, *læran* was more commonly used to mean "teach" than its ancestor, *tæcan*. I'm not sure when the switch from using one to using the other occurred.

Answer (score 4):

It is not quite correct that, as some answers here suggest, this is "the" archaic sense of the word *learn*.

Nor though, is it quite wrong either.

It is **an** archaic sense, that is still found in some dialects.

In the sense of acquiring knowledge, we have *learn* going back as far as Bede and other Old English writers.

In the sense of imparting knowledge, we have *learn* going back not quite so far, but still as far back as Wycliffe's Bible and other Middle English writers.

That it is today labelled "vulgar" in some dictionaries means that it remains current in some dialects, but is not generally considered standard or the language an educated person would use. Still, a book considered definitive enough on the Scouse dialect to have been used in the old [IANA language registration](http://www.iana.org/assignments/lang-tag-apps/en-scouse) has the wonderful title, *Lern Yourself Scouse*.

> The classic example is 'that will learn them!', as in "Shoot all criminals - that will learn them!". I thought this was being deliberately wrong for comedic effect, in keeping with the general sentiment of the sentence.

It depends on the speaker. Some people whose dialect would not have them normally use *learn* in this sense will still use the expression "that'll learn you" and variants ("that'll learn them" and other objects that it will "learn"). It does indeed use a degree of humour, though it's not so much that it is incorrect (and hence at odds with the statement) as just a common enough expression among those whose dialect *does* allow for that use, as to have become an idiom. In particular, some dialects would allow this sense of *learn* only informally, and therefore to use such an informal expression when this sense of the word doesn't otherwise exist in your dialect at all is actively informal. The humour isn't in "being wrong" it's in taking pains to be informal.

Of course, one can still make use of it as humorously uneducated too. When Wodehouse has an upper-class character say of the English public school system, "If you ask me, they don't learn the little perishers nothing." then it is precisely this sort of humour.

When however, Twain writes "Then he remarked that he had undertaken to 'learn' me all about a steamboat, and had done it;" he is distancing his narrator from the use with quotes, but reporting on a realistic use, rather than poking fun.

Comment: Yes. Additional example include, [Learn You Some Erlang for great good!](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/) and [Learn You a Haskell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781593272838.do).

Comment: @EllieKesselman I'm not very familiar with either Erlang or Haskell. Is there a reason why those programming languages would make those phrasings particularly apt?

Comment: I don't know, and have wondered about that too! Is it a gimmick? Or is there something about them as functional languages? I wish I knew where to ask that question!

Comment: I tried asking here, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/267474/is-there-a-reason-for-this-syntax-in-haskell-and-erlang but it was closed

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @JSBangs said, you might consider the possibility that the word is being used by the authors in a humorous or ironic sense.

Comment: The most common ironic phrasing is along the lines of "That'll learn 'em!"  (Meaning roughly "They'll know better than to try THAT again.")

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the word's archaic meaning is "teach," and sometimes words come to mean their opposites, so people are reversing it again today. I once found a list of archaic words and their definitions on Oxford Dictionaries, and it showed some words that mean their opposites, or something close to their opposites. For example, "let" used to mean hinder. I remember "let" meaning "hinder" in *Hamlet* when I studied it, it's a damn good play.

Answer (score 1):

The original meaning of the word "learn" is "to teach." It is the archaic usage of the word according to the OED. Also, this is commonly taught in American high school English classes and is common knowledge. It isn't for comedic effect unless the usage is contemporary. It is likely an older text.

Comment: None of this contradicts JSBangs' careful answer  (encapsulated in the OEDs "Now *vulgar*"), except your claim that this is the original sense, which is unsupported. (But I don't see any reason to downvote.)

Comment: This sense of the word *learn* is very old indeed, back to around 1200 CE, but the other sense is older still by around 300 years.

Comment: Hi this is a good answer Gerald, but would be better with a link to a source.

Comment: I don't understand this, "Also, this is commonly taught in American high school English classes and is common knowledge." To what do you refer?