# If it's incorrect to "learn" someone, then why is "learned man" correct?

Tags: etymology, grammaticality

I am well aware that "learn" is incorrect when used as "teach" (referenced in [Is 'learn' the new 'teach'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/14778/10041)). So why is "learned" common fare, since it is apparently just a participial version of the incorrect usage?

[image]

<sup>Chart from [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+learned%2Ca+wise%2Ca+knowledgeable%2Can+experienced%2Can+erudite%2Can+educated%2Ca+scholarly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20learned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20wise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20knowledgeable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20experienced%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20erudite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20educated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20scholarly%3B%2Cc0)</sup>

Comment: 'Learnèd' means someone who has learned. No contradiction.

Comment: @peterG That's not how participles work, though. A hammered nail is not a nail that has hammered.

Comment: no, that's true, but the distinction is between 'Learnèd' pronounced 'learn-ed' and 'learned' pronounced 'learnd'. . .so I suspect it's not simply a participle.

Comment: I wondered about the unusual pronunciation of *-ed* as a separate syllable, but I can't find any evidence that it denotes any difference from a regular participle.

Comment: Well, I'd say that that is key - you'd be right about 'learnd', of course. Yet I understand that originally all the -ed participles were sounded. . .in which case, your original point would stand. No doubt someone wiser will be along with a proper answer shortly . . .  I added the accent to the last e to make that distinction; it used to be relatively commonplace to do that but it seems to have died out now.

Comment: @peterG because people can't work out how to type it.

Comment: Interesting graph - but what does it really represent? Usage of the expressions across time, perhaps? Maybe the decline in the popular perception of "learning" as the literacy rate increased?

Comment: @Magoo that's a graph generated by Google ngram. It's a free tool you can use to query word usage across the years for all books catalogued in the Google Books project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth considering why people developed the idea that *learn* for *teach* is incorrect.

As detailed in some of the answers you link to, the word *learn* originally had two fully-accepted meanings; to acquire knowledge and skills (as it is still uncontroversially used today) and to impart knowledge and skills (a synonym for *teach*).

Indeed, *learn* is in fact an etymological merging of one word derived from *leornian* (acquire knowledge) and another derived from *læran* (impart knowledge). As such, they should perhaps not be thought of as the same word at all, but as two homonyms. Notably the obsolete (perhaps remaining in some dialects) variant *lere* is a variant only of the sense meaning "to teach".

At this time we could of course use the participle *learned* to mean someone who had been taught a lot, because it was uncontroversial to use *learn* to mean teach. Therefore someone who had been taught was learned.

This participle use came to mean not just that the person had been taught something, but that they had been taught a lot. It also came to include auto-didacts. As it acquired this nuance that went beyond the meaning inherent in the use of the participle as a modifier it became an adjective separate to its verb origin; "A learned man" meant something that went beyond "A man who has been taught".

Now, it's worth considering why *learn* became considered incorrect relatively recently.

It's hard to be sure this is what was at play here (I don't know of any work arguing the case), but one trait that recurred among the prescriptivists of the 18th and 19th century was a desire for logic and well-ordered coordination between words with little overlap.

Take for example the words *less* and *fewer*:

*Fewer* can only be applied to countable nouns; I can have fewer peas but I can't pour fewer sauce on them. *Less* can be applied to both countable and uncountable nouns; I can have less peas and pour less sauce on them. This irritated some people and so *less* was beaten back to **only** deal with uncountable nouns. (In fairness, it was stated in 1770 as a preference rather than a rule, and it's a perfectly reasonable preference).

Most nouns and verbs have a grammatical number; a given form is either singular or plural. *None* is both singular and plural. This irritated some people and so *none* was beaten back to **only** be singular. (I don't actually have a source for this being given as a rule, but I do know of Archbishop Lowth arguing against it, which suggests it was around that time that it came into being).

It seems a reasonable conjecture to suppose that a similar preference was at play here: *Learn* can mean both acquiring and imparting knowledge while *teach* can mean only imparting knowledge, and so *learn* was beaten back to **only** mean acquiring knowledge. (Even though strictly those were two separate homonyms).

This would not have applied to the adjectival use: *Learned* means having a lot of knowledge and… and that's it. There isn't a rival. There isn't an overlap. Perhaps if we also had the expression "a taught man" meaning the same thing, then *learned* in this adjectival use would also have come to be considered incorrect, but we didn't, so it wasn't. (We do have "well-taught", but the slightly different form and slightly different meaning ["well-taught" excludes the autodidact while *learned* now does not] means there isn't a direct analogy).

The fact that *learned* as an adjective already implied more than just the consideration of its meaning as a predicate would suggest no doubt helped insulate it from this culling of senses from *learn*. Afterwards the declined of that sense of *learn* would have only further strengthened the independence of the adjective.

Answer (score 12):

According to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=learn&allowed_in_frame=0)

> The transitive sense (*He learned me how to read*), now vulgar, was acceptable from c.1200 until early 19c., from Old English *læran* "to teach" (cognates: Dutch *leren*, German *lehren* "to teach," literally "to make known;" see [*lore*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lore&allowed_in_frame=0)), and is preserved in past participle adjective [***learned***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=learned&allowed_in_frame=0) "having knowledge gained by study."

Comment: The *is preserved* is the part I would like to explore. Perhaps I won't get further than this, though.

Comment: Are you asking *why* this particular form of the now-vulgar usage has survived?  That question will likely go begging, barring some possibly-informed guesswork. My guess would be that when "learned" was first being used, it was the only term that applied, as "educated" would not emerge until the 1660's (etymonline again), and wouldn't actually mean well-educated until 1855 (prior to that, apparently "educated" simply meant "attended school").  This timing seems to correspond to the fading of *learned* being used in the transitive sense.

Comment: Since educated implies having had formal schooling while learned may simply mean trained through various formal and informal means, it's possible that "learned" has been retained to emphasize that slight difference in connotation.

Comment: @MarkThompson Correct - it would have helped if I had included the etymonline entry in my question; all it does is finger the point, not answer it.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that the *n* in *learned* is a "correction" that shouldn't have happened. In the [*Speculum Vitae*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculum_Vitae), among other Middle English sources, we find this form:

> Bothe **lered** and lewed, olde and yonge,
>
> Alle vnderstonden english tonge.

*Lewed* has since become *lewd*, and like its friends *rude* and *homely*, has acquired a connotation that wasn't there to begin with. At the time, it simply meant uneducated or unlettered, the opposite of *lered*.

We have managed to keep the pronounced *e* in the ending (and sometimes mark it with a grave accent in spelling, as *learnèd*) that marks the word as an adjective rather than the past tense of a verb (and have done so more strongly than in other similar words); the *n*, which used to mark the verb form, likely came in because people crave consistency to the point that they make their languages inconsistent to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in English grammar, but in the phrase "a learned man", the "learned" is pronounced "learnid".  Not pronounced like "he learned", so while it is spelt the same it is a different word/meaning or different form of it.

Comment: You're correct about the pronunciation - but are you sure it's a different form?

Comment: @Daniel I don't know exactly what constitutes 'different form' but to my ear it sounds like a different word or different form. Thinking about it more. "a learned man" that's an adjective.so in that sense it's a different form of word. Whether it's technically thought of as a different word or not I don't know.But in the sense of it being an adjective it is a different form to "he learned geography".I suppose the adjective form of teach is teachable. A teachable student.  I suppose learned(as in learnid) and learned(as in the verb) are same word but definitely different form(adjective, verb).

Comment: The extra syllable does occur in participial adjectives such as _aged_, _dogged_, and _learned_. The participial adjective _blessed_ may be pronounced as a monosyllable, like the past participle, according to Collins.  _Wicked_ (adj; evil) and _wicked_ (past tense of wick, or participial adjective; single syllable) are homographs.

Comment: Learned is an adjective, and implies the past tense.  "He learned" is perfectly valid.  By using the word as an adjective "He is a learned man."  It implies that *He* learned something at some point in the past.  Hence, the term: "a learned man".  (The origin being something along the lines of: "a well-learned man".)

Comment: @Builder_K So, "a closed window" would also imply that the window closed itself at some point in the past?

Comment: I think you hit it on the head; to say that someone is a learn-ed man would be to say that he is someone who is well-learned. One can learn for themselves or one can teach others but one cannot learn someone else, although it IS okay to teach yourself and to learn from others.

Comment: @user2338816 "a closed window" The window was closed at some point in the past.  There is no implication that the window closed itself.

Comment: @RonKyle but one can indeed, or at least could indeed, learn someone else, and *learned* the adjective does come from the use "I learned him his algebra", as much as that fell into disfavour in the 1800s.