# Is it correct to use "learn" as a synonym for "teach"?

Tags: meaning

I have recently been noticing many people using "learn" as a synonym for "teach", as in

> Mr. Smith learned you how to do long division.

How common is this? Is it considered "correct"? It sounds strange to me. Google lists this usage as the second definition of "learn", and as both archaic and informal.

Comment: It is not correct in standard English, but has been used in various dialects— and jokingly or mockingly to indicate a poor education. See *[Is 'learn' the new 'teach'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14778/is-learn-the-new-teach)*

Comment: It is a dialect I hear (non-facetiously) in some parts of the rural US.  Certainly far from "mainstream".